How could I get my program's functions when using perf and converting the data in JSON?
I'd like to use the tool perf to know how much time was needed to execute each method of a program I've made in Smalltalk (Pharo), however I'd also like to get the data in JSON through the perf data convert --to-json command after having done perf record ....
For now, it only gives the system calls whereas if I do the perf report > file.txt I get the Smalltalk's methods but the data is not really parsable.
I'm on Pop OS, kernel 6.8.0
Does anyone have any idea of how I could fix that?
From the txt file I get something like this :
        12.42%     0.00%  pharo            libPharoVMCore.so                            [.] runOnMainThread (inlined)
                |
                ---runOnMainThread (inlined)
                   runVMThread (inlined)
                   |          
                   |--8.50%--loadPharoImage
                   |          readImageNamed
                   |          allocateMemoryForImagewithHeader.isra.0
                   |          initializeObjectMemory
                   |          |          
                   |           --0.51%--lastPointerOfWhileSwizzling
                   |          
                    --3.93%--interpret
                              enterSmalltalkExecutiveImplementation
                              interpret
                              |          
                               --3.24%--primitiveAllInstances
                                         allInstancesOf

And the JSON file gives me something like this (they do not represent the same sample but come from the same perf.data file) :
    {
    "timestamp": 19015602195292,
    "pid": 19473,
    "tid": 19473,
    "comm": "pharo",
    "callchain": [
    {
        "ip": "0xffffffff92611bfa",
        "symbol": "handle_mm_fault",
        "dso": "[kernel.kallsyms]"
    },
    {
        "ip": "0xffffffff922cb588",
        "symbol": "do_user_addr_fault",
        "dso": "[kernel.kallsyms]"
    },
    {
        "ip": "0xffffffff933e2693",
        "symbol": "exc_page_fault",
        "dso": "[kernel.kallsyms]"
    },
    {
        "ip": "0xffffffff93400ba7",
        "symbol": "asm_exc_page_fault",
        "dso": "[kernel.kallsyms]"
    }
    ]
    },

I'd like to get the same information from the txt but in the JSON file so that I can esaily parse it.
I've read the documentation of perf many times but couldn't find anything helping that was still supported in 6.8.0
